# SharePoint critical error

Tags: moss

[image: Parser Error]

```
This page has encountered a critical error. Contact your system administrator if this problem persists.
```

```
Line 1: <%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~TemplatePageUrl" %>; <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~masterurl/custom.master" %> <html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"><head>
Line 2:  <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
Line 3: <mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
```

MOSS is occasionally throwing this error as soon as I log on and attempt to access any page. I have discovered a very strange workaround: if I take a fresh web.config from an empty web application and copy over the web.config of the problematic web.config, and then paste in all the special configuration changes I need, it works. However, if I save a backup of a working web.config and then revert to it when the error appears, it doesn't seem to resolve it. I have to start over from a fresh one. It almost seems to me like a corruption issue in the web.config, and it generally appears after I make a change somewhere else on the server, on at least one occasion it happened without any apparent update to the timestamp of the web.config. Furthermore, there is no corruption evident in the file, even if I diff against a fresh web.config.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may be having a similar issue, I found the problem. I guess when I originally set up the web application in SharePoint Central Administration I used a particular directory, but then changed it in IIS. Now when I make certain changes in central admin, SharePoint tries to look for the application/web.config in the original directory. In order to fix it, I have to go back in to IIS and update the home directory of the web site to the new directory.